# IS there a way to generate allure report from RobotFramework already existing report

Tags: robotframework, allure

I know how to use Allure with RobotFramework as listener, this the obivious way.

But, I want ton know if there is a way to generate an allure report from an existing RobotFramewrok Reports?

Thank You